# Extracting data from a complex array without lots of FOR loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a fairly complex array generated from Google's natural language API. I feed it a paragraph of text and out comes lots of language information regarding such paragraph.

My end goal is to find "key words" from this paragraph, so, to achieve this I want to put all the "entities" into a flat array, count the duplicates, and then consider words with the highest amount of duplicates to be "key words". If it doesn't find any then I'll cherry pick words from entities I consider most significant.

I already know the entities that *could* exist:

```
var entities = [
    'art',
    'events',
    'goods',
    'organizations',
    'other',
    'people',
    'places',
    'unknown'
];
```

Here is an example structure of the array I'm working with.

```
input = [
{
 language: {
  entities: {
   people: [
    {
     name: "Paul",
     type: "Person",
    },
    {
     name: "Paul",
     type: "Person",
    },
   ],
   goods: [
    {
     name: "car",
     type: "Consumer_good",
    }
   ], //etc
  }
 }
}
];

output = ["Paul", "Paul", "car"...];
```

My question is - what is the best way to convert my initial array into a flat array to then find the duplicates **without** using a whole bunch of FOR loops?

Comment: Use one loop to go through your main array of objects. Ask its property to be an array. Loop through that and push item to a result array if its not already indexOf of your result array.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around loops or array functions if you work with dynamic input data.

Comment: I understand it's fairly unavoidable, I just wanted to know if there was a better way than using a for loop in a for loop in a for loop etc...

Comment: @Aloogy I try to use array functions like `map`, `filter` and `reduce` for situations like these because you have new scope for every iteration and the callbacka are easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through input.language.entities in a recursive way and collect all the .name properties into an array. Then you have only one for loop :-).

After doing that, you can iterate through it to find the duplicates. If you sort it alphabetical before it is easier (if two or more consecutive entries are equal, there are duplicates).

But it could be a bit dangerous if google changes the api or if it delivers crap data because of a malfunction.

Isn't input.language.entities already flat enough to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access all the values using this format:

```
input[0]["language"]["entities"]["people"][0].name
```

```js
input = [
{
 language: {
  entities: {
   people: [
    {
     name: "Paul",
     type: "Person",
    },
    {
     name: "Paul",
     type: "Person",
    },
   ],
   goods: [
    {
     name: "car",
     type: "Consumer_good",
    }
   ], //etc
  }
 }
}
];
console.log(input[0]["language"]["entities"]["people"][0].name);
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
for (var entry in input[0]["language"]["entities"]) {
    console.log(entry);
}
```

**OR**, if I understood you wrong,

You can use this to turn the javascript Object into an array using this (requires jquery):

```js
var myObj = {
    1: [1, 2, 3],
    2: [4, 5, 6]
};

var array = $.map(myObj, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});


console.log(array[0][0]);
console.log(array[0]);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will output

```
1

[1, 2, 3]

[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like this. It's not pretty but it gets the job done.

```
var result = [];
var known_entities = ['art','events','goods','organizations','other','people','places','unknown'];          
    for(i=0; i < known_entities.length; i++){
        var entity = known_entities[i];
        if(language.entities[entity]){
           for(var j in language.entities[entity]){
              var word = language.entities[entity][j].name
              result.key_words.push(word);
           }
        }
    }
```